# Django and Docker: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget_tweaks'

Tags: django, docker, django-widget-tweaks

I'm trying to use `django-widget-tweaks` in my web application (using Django and Docker), but it is not being recognized as an installed package.

My DockerFile:

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.10.2-slim-bullseye

# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install django-widget-tweaks

# Copy project
COPY . .
```

My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'openai',   
]

INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'widget_tweaks',
]
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
project-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
...
project-web-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget_tweaks'
```

Comment: An reason you are using pip first and then pip3? They probably point to the same executable, but just to be sure.

Comment: I tried it with pip first, but it didn't work. Then some folks online said pip3 worked for them for this particular module, so I edited the run command in my Dockerfile, but no luck.

Comment: @Rob To be clear, this module isn't in my requirements.txt

Comment: I would use the same command (pip/pip3) for all dependencies to make sure they are installed to the same environment. Did you try adding `django-widget-tweaks` to requirements.txt?

Comment: @Rob yep, I tried that first. Didn't work (same error)

Comment: Using the same command (pip/pip3) for both RUN instructions would still be my best guess, for example `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` and `RUN pip install django-widget-tweaks` or `RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt` and `RUN pip3 install django-widget-tweaks`